# Unable to run Pig latin script on Apache Tez

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-tez

I am having a pseudo-distributed single cluster Ubuntu machine. I have written a simple pig latin script which runs fine while using mapreduce as execution mode. But when i use tez as excution mode using -x switch then i got following error

> 2015-08-17 17:12:22,344 [PigTezLauncher-0] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob - Cannot
>   submit DAG org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning: **TezSession has
>   already shutdown**  at
>   org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:603)     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezSessionManager.createSession(TezSessionManager.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezSessionManager.getClient(TezSessionManager.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezJob.run(TezJob.java:159)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.tez.TezLauncher$1.run(TezLauncher.java:167)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I want to know meaning of this exception and how to resolve this issue.

**RESOLVED:**
Problem is with version of pig and tez. Installed tez 0.5 with pig 0.14 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Which command you used for this

```
 pig -x local <file name> or pig -x local -x tez <file name>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem was with version of tez and pig.